# setImageViewUri in widget from Room

Tags: android, android-widget, android-fileprovider

I have an app that allows the users to take images. I then store the image in a local file and save the URI to Room. I then have a widget associated with the app that has an image view. I inject my database into the widget using Dagger-Hilt and successfully pass that URI to my updateAppWidget method

The URI in question:

> file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication/AlbumExpo/2021-11-08-07-37-55-596.jpg

the problem is that the app crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication/AlbumExpo/2021-11-08-07-37-55-596.jpg
```

I have tried many things on similar SO questions, but it feels like I am missing some important information. I think I just don't clearly understand how to use File provider tags on my manifest to correctly point the app to the directory where the app stores my images. I am not sure what to show in terms of code so if you need anything please ask in the comments.

Originally my error was:

```
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication/AlbumExpo/2021-11-08-07-37-55-596.jpg exposed beyond app through RemoteViews.setUri()
```

which was generated when I directly called

```
 views.setImageViewUri(R.id.img_1, Uri.parse(uri.uri))
```

with my original uri from above. To attempt to solve this issue I followed the accepted answer in this
[So question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

that lead me to do:

```
val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    context,
    "com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication.provider",
    File(uri.uri)
)
 views.setImageViewUri(R.id.img_1, photoURI)
```

I am assuming that the process of creating a file from my original uri then re-transforming it to a uri using the file provider makes it's path mutate to what the error says.

Comment: "The URI in question" -- that is not a valid `Uri`. For some reason, you have a leading `/` that should not be there.

Comment: sorry I pasted the wrong text, I have updated the question, the extra / on the error comes from the logger

Comment: The error suggests that your original text was what you are actually using with `FileProvider`, though. The error message shows the same leading `/`.

Comment: I have added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    context,
    "com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication.provider",
    File(uri.uri)
)
```

`uri.uri` appears to be a `String`, with a value of: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication/AlbumExpo/2021-11-08-07-37-55-596.jpg`.

This is a string representation of a `Uri`, one with the `file` scheme. It is not a filesystem path. You cannot pass it to the `File` constructor and get something useful.

You seem to have originally gotten your value via `getExternalMediaDirs()`. You might consider persisting that filesystem path value, rather than converting it into a `Uri` (via `Uri.fromFile()`) with a `file` scheme that you cannot use.

But, given your current `uri.uri` value, you would need to change your code to:

```kotlin
val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    context,
    "com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication.provider",
    File(Uri.parse(uri.uri).path)
)
```

`Uri.parse(uri.uri)` will turn that `String` back into a `Uri`, albeit one with the mostly-useless `file` scheme. `Uri.parse(uri.uri).path` will extract the filesystem path (`/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.sudharsanravikumar.myapplication/AlbumExpo/2021-11-08-07-37-55-596.jpg`). And you pass *that* to the `File` constructor. Always pass filesystem paths to the `File` constructor.

Comment: this worked but now my widget displays "problem loading widget" and I get this on the log, although not marked as an error: 2021-11-17 00:15:56.962 1545-4759/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{ea978f1 2178:com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/u0a152} (pid=2178, uid=10152) that is not exported from UID 10448

Comment: @barryalan2633: Other apps need permission to work with your `FileProvider`. Normally  you do that by using flags on an `Intent` (e.g., `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`). I am uncertain what the solution is for `RemoteViews` and app widgets, though.